# How can I create straight, glowing lines?

Tags: 3d, glow, bloom

What techniques are used in this style?  What steps would be required to recreate it?

[image]

(Screenshot of this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dkeesto.holographlw)

Comment: Why are you sure this is made with some "magic" shader? There are plenty ways of doing this even with Fixed-Function Pipeline.

Comment: isn't a convincing glow effect kind of hard to do with FFP? (blurring in FFP is terribly slow)

Comment: This could be simply just textured polygons.

Comment: @TimothyGroote: There's no need to blur anything in real-time here ;)

Comment: @KromStern well, assuming there are no changes in the glow and shape of the tiles, no. :)

Comment: @TimothyGroote: Even if shapes changed and glow was pulsing - it could still be made with FFP (by just moving and tweaking gradients transparencies).

Answer (score 2):

This is generic solution that will work even with **FFP**:

1. Sort models from far to near (in the example this is just a matter of 2 planes)
2. Set blending to additive.
3. Render opaque outline;
4. Render half-transparent insides;
5. Render outlines with half-transparent fading gradient;
6. Render glowing dots sprites on the corners.

Answer (score 1):

To render just the edges of an arbitrary polygon you could use a [Solid Wireframe technique](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates). It uses barycentric coordinates to determine which edges to draw. For example you might have a triangle whose barycentric coordinates are (for each vertex) `B0: (1, 0, 0) B1: (0, 1, 0) B2: (0, 0, 1)`. Put it simply, when these values are interpolated the further any of the values are close to zero, then the further you are to an edge. You can use this to shade the edges differently than the inside of a the polygon.

I have used this technique to draw the sphere and hexagon tiles you see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TD0PiEMPKUQ). As the others have suggested, you can add a glow/bloom effect to improve the overall effect.

Answer (score 0):

In very crude pseudo-code :

- Draw the "laser lines" to an off screen buffer.

*in case of openGL, this could be a FrameBuffer*

- Then draw the off screen buffer to the screen.
- Blur the off screen buffer

*you could use GLSL shaders, or even a hand coded kernel for this*

- Blend the (now blurred off screen buffer) to the screen (using additive blending)

*note that additive blending in OPENGL is done by subtraction!*